# MVC - Convert PdfPTable to Html

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pdf

I am working on downloading a `PDF document`. I have used `PdfPTable` to create a table. Below is my shortened code.

```
var document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 50, 50, 25, 25);                
var output = new MemoryStream();
var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, output);

document.Open();

PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
table.WidthPercentage = 80;

PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Description", fntTableFontBold));
cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
table.AddCell(cell);

......
document.Add(table);
document.Close();

Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment;filename={0}.pdf", "Journal"));
Response.BinaryWrite(output.ToArray());
```

All is working fine. Above code straight away downloads the PDF in browser.

Now i want to add Preview functionality, If the User clicks on `Preview`, He should see the HTML output.

How to convert this above code to show as `HTML`? There is lots of code & queries which are used for creating `PdfPTable`.

Comment: You already answered your question: *there is lots of code & queries which are used for creating PdfPTable*. Do not use all that to create `PdfTable`. Create some intermediate object (list, array, etc.) which then will be used to create PdfTable or generate HTML.

Comment: Its already being used in more than 30 pages with complicated queries, what is the solution now?

Comment: Well, you can convert `PdfTable` to html: enumerate rows, columns, cells, etc. to get data from `PdfTable` and then generate html. But it's wrong (double work). Think about pdf and html as targets and your database (or what are you querying) as a source. All queries and logic should generate *something* intermediate (structured as a table), what then can be used by either target in most easy way.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a pdf using iTextSharp involves a lot of coding. You cannot render a pdf as HTML code (that I know of), but you can create an HTML first, convert it into a pdf and then render the pdf as stream to a browser. If you are creating the HTML first then you can use the html for preview.

Here is a block of code that I once wrote to convert html to pdf.

```
protected void ConvertHTMLToPDF(String HTMLCode, String fileName)
{    
    //Create PDF document 
    iTextSharp.text.Document doc = new iTextSharp.text.Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4);
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~") + "/Resources/Temp/" + fileName, FileMode.Create));
    doc.Open();

    foreach (IElement element in HTMLWorker.ParseToList(new StringReader(HTMLCode), null))                
    {
        doc.Add(element);
    }

    doc.Close();
    //Response.End();

}
```